# cannot resolve symbol ListView and ArrayAdapter

Tags: android-layout

I am getting cannot resolve symbol for ListView and ArrayAdapter ,trying to resolve for a long time,suggestions plz.
res/layout contains `activity_main.xml`,`fragment.xml` and `layout_textview.xml`

**fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.sunshine.BlankFragment">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >
    </ListView>
</FrameLayout>

layout_textview.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:id="@+id/text_view">

</TextView>
```

**BlankFragment.java**

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {
    private View rootview;
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> itemAdapter;

    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootview= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

        String[] forecastArray={"Monday-sunny","Tuesday-cloudy","wednesday-sunny","Thursday-rain","friday-cloudy","saturday-sunny","sunday-cloudy"};
        List<String> weekforecast=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));
         itemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.layout_textview,R.id.text_view, weekforecast);

        listView=(ListView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.listView);
         listView.setAdapter(weekforecast);

        return rootview;
    }

}
```

Comment: What are the `import` statements to your fragment?

Comment: thank u,after including import statements for ListView and ArrayAdapter so its working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {
    private View rootview;
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> itemAdapter;

    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         // Inflate the layout for this fragment
         View rootview= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

         String[] forecastArray={"Monday-sunny","Tuesday-cloudy","wednesday-sunny","Thursday-rain","friday-cloudy","saturday-sunny","sunday-cloudy"};

         final List<String> weekforecast=new ArrayList<String>();

         for (int i = 0; i < forecastArray.length; ++i) 
         {
                        weekforecast.add(forecastArray[i]);
         }

         final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
                                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, weekforecast);


        listView=(ListView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootview;
    }
```

Try this code

Comment: Thank u,there was mistake  in listView.setAdapter(adapter);